# Higher Order component not rendering the component from routes

Tags: reactjs

I am updating the prop of child component, before them placed with layout component. But seems not work.

this function not works:

```
   function HigherOrderHandler(component) {
  const {name} = AuthHook();
  class withPropComponent extends React.component {
    render() {
      return  (<component name={name} />);
    }
  }
  return withPropComponent;
}
```

here is my routes.js file.

```
import { Layout } from 'layouts';
import AuthHook from './../hooks/auth.hook';
import React from 'react';

import {
  AOPSPage, 
  TransHomePage, 
  CreateNewTransaction,
  MissingTransactionPage, 
  PDetailPage, 
  LandingPage, 
  UserRolePage, 
  ReportPG
} from 'pages';



    function HigherOrderHandler(component) {
  const {name} = AuthHook();
  class withPropComponent extends React.component {
    render() {
      return  (<component name={name} />);
    }
  }
  return withPropComponent;
}

// ROUTES HAV ROOT IS SET ON (config/env) BASE_PATH=/
const routes = [
  {
    component: Layout,
    path: '*',
    routes: [
      {
        path: '/',
        exact: true,
        component: HigherOrderHandler(LandingPage) //adding props
      },
      {
        path: '/fin-csas-app-ui',
        exact: true,
        component: LandingPage
      },
      {
        path: process.env.BASE_PATH,
        exact: false,
        component: AOPSPage
      },
      {
        path: '/AOPS',
        exact: true,
        component: AOPSPage
      },
      {
        path: '/Translation',
        exact: true,
        component: TransHomePage
      },
      {
        path: '/Details/:orderNum',
        exact: true,
        component: PDetailPage
      },
      {
        path: '/Landing',
        exact: true,
        component: LandingPage
      },
      {
        path: '/UserRoleAssignment',
        exact: true,
        component: UserRolePage
      },
      {
        path: '/Reports',
        exact: true,
        component: ReportPG
      },
      {
        path: '/CreateTransaction',
        exact: true,
        component: CreateNewTransaction
      },
      {
        path: '/MissingTransaction',
        exact: true,
        component: MissingTransactionPage
      }
    ]
  }
];

export default routes;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my function in to functional way. it works fine.

```
function HigherOrderHandler(OriginalComponent) {
    function NewComponent(props) {
      return <OriginalComponent city={'chennai'} />
    }
    return NewComponent;
}
  
  export default HigherOrderHandler;
```